# Show that for all $a>1: |\sqrt{a^2-1}-a|<1$.

Tags: analysis, inequality

Using triangle inequalities don't lead me anywhere. The derivative wrt $a$ gives $$\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}-1$$ which to my mind isn't super helpful either. Graphing $|\sqrt{a^2-1}-a|$ shows the inequality to be true though.

We know that for $a>1$ we find an upper bound for the root $\sqrt{a}<a$ but when $a>1$ we just have $a^2-1>0$.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}=\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is $|-a+\sqrt{a^2-1}|<1<|-a-\sqrt{a^2-1}|$ (where $a>1$) true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3796517/why-is-a-sqrta2-11-a-sqrta2-1-where-a1-true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hastily wrote an incorrect answer to this question initially. I have rewritten it, leaving the incorrect version at the bottom. Thanks @Brian Moehring for pointing out the error.

First note if $a>1$ then $\sqrt{a-1} < \sqrt{a +1}$. We have:
$$a-1 = \sqrt{a-1}\sqrt{a-1}<\sqrt{a+1}\sqrt{a-1} = \sqrt{a^2 -1}$$

Hence, $a - \sqrt{a^2 -1} <1$. Therefore,
$$|a - \sqrt{a^2 -1}| = |\sqrt{a^2 -1} -a| < 1$$

The following is the previous (incorrect) answer:

> $a^2 < a^2 + 2a + 2$ for all positive $a$ (in particular, $a>1$). So
> taking 1 from both sides we get: $a^2 -1 < a^2 + 2a + 1 = ( a + 1)^2$
> and so $\sqrt{a^2 - 1} < \sqrt{(a + 1)^2} = a+1$.
>
> Hence, $\sqrt{a^2 - 1} -a < 1$, when $a>1$. In particular, $|
> > \sqrt{a^2 - 1} - a| < 1$.